# additionalModelTypeAnnotations for specific class

Tags: spring-boot

I would like to add an annotation only for a specific class while using the `open-api-generator`. Is this possible. Currently I use `additionalModelTypeAnnotations` and this seems to be adding the annotation for all the classes. Is there an alternate option?

```
<configOptions><additionalModelTypeAnnotations>@com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize(using = com.test.java.data.CustomDeserializer.class)</additionalModelTypeAnnotations>
    <sourceFolder>models</sourceFolder>
    <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
    <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
    </configOptions>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  I too have the issue where if I specify

<additionalModelTypeAnnotations>@lombok.Builder @lombok.AllArgsConstructor</additionalModelTypeAnnotations>

It adds the annotations to the abstract class AbstractOpenApiSchema.  This is obviously incorrect as the code won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

I finally ended up using `aspectj` where I can use compile time weaving to add the annotations.